Prompt Template for Sequence matching using LlamaIndex and Llama3-70B-Instruct
I'm trying to get llama3-70b to find all sequences that match a given list. The list contains multiple terms (which range from one word to twelve words). I want the model to match all terms in a given piece of text; the text is about one to two paragraphs long.
This is the prompt template that I've tried:
template = (
"We have provided context information below. \n"
"---------------------\n"
"{context_str}"
"\n---------------------\n"
"Given this information, please find all terms (matching on all words in the term), from the given context, in this input sentence: \n"
"\n---------------------\n"
"{query_str}"
"\n---------------------\n"
"Identify and return the terms from the given context that are found in the input sentence as list_cancer_terms. Additionally, return list_of_sentences where each term is preceded by the seven words before it and followed by the seven words after it in the input sentence. Provide the response in JSON format only."
# <|im_end|>\n")

Llama3 returns terms that aren't even in the context. How can I get around this issue?
Edit:
Adding code snippets and example text
model_name_or_path = "crusoeai/Llama-3-70B-Instruct-Gradient-262k-GGUF"
model_basename = "llama-3-70b-instruct-gradient-262k.Q4_K_M.gguf"
model_path = hf_hub_download(repo_id=model_name_or_path, filename=model_basename)


llm = Llama(
      model_path=model_path,
      chat_format="llama-3",
      n_ctx=12288,
      # Verbose=True,
      echo=True,
      n_threads=4,
      n_gpu_layers=-1,
      temperature=0,
      top_k=1
    
)

qa_template = PromptTemplate(template)
result_sentence = "A.  Bladder right wall biopsy: - High-grade papillary urothelial carcinoma. - Invasive into at least the lamina propria. "

data_cancer = [MYELOMA,carcinoma]


prompt = qa_template.format(context_str=data_cancer, query_str=result_sentence, pydantic_schema=pydantic_schema)


messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant that only answers in JSON. Here's the json schema you must adhere to:\n<schema>\n{{" + pydantic_schema + "}}\n<schema>\n"},
    {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
]

Above is the llamaindex and llama.cpp code that I'm using. I also included an example of the text (i.e. result_sentence) and list that I'm passing (data_cancer).
The issue I'm facing is that instead of just returning carcinoma, which is the only word from the list in the text, the model is returning "papillary urothelial carcinoma".

I would suggest adding some code of what you are doing, otherwise it is not possible to know what is not working.

I've added the llamaindex and llama.cpp code that I'm using. Also, added a bit of the text and list that are used as part of the inference. Let me know if anything else is needed.
